# Multiple string search to return Cell

Tags: google-sheets, search, filter, find

I'm looking for a filter or search that will return the correct name based on keywords existing in a cell. Please help!
Here is the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eDiHQ6UaDEcIMKt1GNNl5DKD0FtxipVOX-kBoCzLdnQ/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C9 try

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(regexextract(A9:A11, textjoin("|", 1, substitute(B2:B4, ", ", "|"))), split(flatten(split(B2:B4, ", ")&"_"&A2:A4), "_"), 2, 0)))
```

and see if that works?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&IF(REGEXMATCH(""&
 SPLIT(A9:A, " ,.?!"), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SUBSTITUTE(B2:B4, ", ", "|"))), 
 SPLIT(A9:A, " .,?!"), NA())&"*", {B2:B4, A2:A4}, 2, 0))),,9^9))))
```

[image]

Comment: What great code, don't know if I ever would have got there, thanks!